# php роутинг. преимущество использования

Tags: php, роутинг

Всем привет.

Почему, применяя маршрутизацию используют именно такой подход

**[www.my.site/docs/writes/news?id=7](http://www.my.site/docs/writes/news?id=7)**

а не набор GET параметров

**[www.my.site/index.php?docs=writes&news=7](http://www.my.site/index.php?docs=writes&news=7)**

Ведь короче проверить существование get параметра (isset($_GET['X'])) чем распарсить url и потом проверять наличие определенного пути в нем.

В чем преимущество первого варианта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основные причины использования ЧПУ ("Человекопонятный URL"):

- Удобство использования, они более естественны и интуитивно понятны.
  Такие ссылки обычно позволяют определить структуру приложения, а
  также содержимое, просто по названию.
- SEO-оптимизация. Использование ЧПУ - один из факторов, который
  учитывают поисковые системы при ранжировании сайта. Собственно, этого
  одного фактора достаточно, чтобы решить: использовать ЧПУ или нет.
- Во многих приложениях используется шаблон FrontController с единой
  точкой входа, ей делегируется маршрутизация, которую пишете вы сами.
  И нет никакой причины писать сложно `?docs=writes&news=7`, когда
  можно написать просто `/docs/writes/news/7`

Насчет *распарсить url* - не нужно его парсить. Вы настраиваете правила либо на сервере (к примеру .htaccess для апаче), или у себя в своей единой точке входа. В любом случае вы пишете простой набор правил: **'ссылка' *=>* 'что запустить'**.

Ну да, и приведенный пример не совсем корректен:

> [www.my.site/docs/writes/news?id=7](http://www.my.site/docs/writes/news?id=7)

вы говорите, что пишут так, но так не пишут. Это либо `news/7`, либо `news/article_header` , то есть название именно новости текущей, а не ее `id`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, тем, что для конечного пользователя эта ссылка более понятна. Тем более можно упростить задачу, используя файл `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^docs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/news?id=([0-9]+)$ index.php?docs=$1&news=$2
```